# Remove all the parentheses and replace all spaces by underscores?

Tags: python, string, replace

Here is what I did:

```
import re
def demicrosoft (fn):

    fn = re.sub('[()]', '', fn)
    for ch in [' ']:
        fn = fn.replace(ch,"_"+ch)
    return fn
print(demicrosoft('a bad file name (really)'))
```

```
>>> (executing lines 1 to 12 of "<tmp 2>")
a_ bad_ file_ name_ really
```

There are spaces followed with the underscores. How can I fix it?

Comment: Why are you adding the space back `'_'+ch` - `ch` is a space? Don't you just mean `'_'` - as you are trying to replace the `' '` with a `'_'` and `ch` is a `' '`.

Comment: Why not just `return re.sub('[()]', '', fn).replace(' ', '_')`

Comment: Why is having spaces, parenthesis and square brackets in filename bad? They're all valid filename characters on modern filesystems.

Comment: @Anthon Sure, and ελληνικά or العربية characters make up for good file (and variable) names too.

Comment: Why do you use `re` for one substitution, and `replace` for the other? It is the same functionality (and `re` is an overkill btw).

Comment: @n.caillou I don't agree with that. Going beyond ASCII has severe consequences e.g with keyboard input.

Answer (score 3):

You can just chain a number of `replace`s for this:

```
a = 'a bad file name (really)'

>>> a.replace('(', '').replace(')', '').replace(' ', '_')
'a_bad_file_name_really'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `str.translate()`:

```
>>> table = str.maketrans({'(':None, ')':None, ' ':'_'})
>>> 'a bad file name (really)'.translate(table)
'a_bad_file_name_really'
```

Answer (score 1):

remove **ch** from **"_"+ch** in replace call as follows

```
import re
def demicrosoft (fn):

    fn = re.sub('[()]', '', fn)
    for ch in [' ']:
        fn = fn.replace(ch,"_")
    return fn
```